# How can I set an html node's innerText and innerHtml without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, innertext

In javaScript, how can I set an html nodes inner text and inner html without using jQuery?

Here is what I have tried:

```
function setInnerText(className, data) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(className).innerText(data);
}

function setInnerHTML(className, data) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(className).innerHTML(data);
}
```

May I please have some help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that *innerText* is not a W3C standard, the (standards compliant) equivalent is *textContent*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName#Syntax) returns a collection of elements. To set the `innerText` of first element, use

```
document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0].innerText(data);
```

You can also use `querySelector`

```
document.querySelector('.' + className).innerText = data;
```

To set the `innerText` of all the elements,

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
// var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.' + className);

for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].innerText = data;
}
```